# gsutil Cerfificate failure

Tags: google-app-engine, gsutil

I recently updated to lates GAE SDK. Gsutil started not working, so I deleted cacerts.txt, as suggested on another post here, but it did not work.

`Failure: CA certificates file does not have expected SHA1 sum; expected:ed0... actual: da39a3ee5e6...`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What are you doing? What is the unexpected result?

Comment: gsutil ls, cp, etc.   I can do in my other machine.

Comment: OK,  removing and reinstalling fixed it.